# Load JSON in d3.js to draw scatterplot

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am just trying my hand on d3.js and I am already in trouble.
As per my knowledge, the second parameter passed in d3.json() can be used to process data from json.

My code is :

```
 d3.json(base_url() + "data/data.json", clean_data)
   .then(function (dataset) {
      global_dataset = dataset;
      console.log(dataset.age);
  })
 .catch(() => console.log("could not load a file"));

function clean_data(d) {
 console.log("i am here");
 let balance = d.balance;
 balance = balance.splice(1);
 return { age: +d.age, balance: +balance };
}
```

In my code console.log(dataset) is giving me original JSON data rather than processed object returned by clean_data() function.

**My JSON data look like this**:

[**JSON URL**](https://next.json-generator.com/V1OqfcoK_)

In my HTML for this, I have included CDN of d3.js :

```
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to make scatterplot from this JSON  using d3.js and promise.

Comment: *"As per my knowledge, the second parameter passed in d3.json() can be used to process data from json"*. No, that's incorrect, `d3.json` does not accept a row function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have miss-understood how to use [d3.json()](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json), `d3.json()` in v5 takes the first parameter URL and the [second parameter is option object](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) (since d3.json is a wrapper for [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)), which is the URL for your JSON server, then it will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) fulfilled upon success and rejected upon failure, so you have to iterate over your JSON response and add it to an Array or maybe use the well known D3.js - [enter(), update() and exit() pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5), here is an example of what you might do to get your data:

```js
const data = [];

d3.json('https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/V1OqfcoK_')
 .then(function (dataset) {
   dataset.forEach((d, i) => {
     data.push({age: +d.age, balance: +Number(d.balance.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ""))});
   });
   // once done iterating over dataset we can use it
   console.log(data);
})
.catch(() => console.log("could not load a file"));
```

```html
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```